# Can't find Ubuntu in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, efibootmgr

I installed Ubuntu from my USB, and after I looked at the efibootmgr, I don't know what to do.

[image: sudo efibootmgr -v]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0001,0002,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,49e5d567-d509-41e2-8a10-f5fd0b5d8ae4,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,49e5d567-d509-41e2-8a10-f5fd0b5d8ae4,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* Linpus lite   HD(1,MBR,0x4294967271,0x2caa70,0x1280)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0003* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,49e5d567-d509-41e2-8a10-f5fd0b5d8ae4,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

When I reboot I go straight to windows, and when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and go into BIOS and boot, it does not say Ubuntu on any of them. I don't know what may cause this, anyone got any ideas how to be able to boot both?

I followed the tutorial, came to the last step, but my efibootmgr looks different and I don't get much of it http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

After I turn off my computer I can't get into Ubuntu again, I have to put my stick in again and use it for a live boot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add Terminal output directly into your question. Thanks!

Comment: Boot0000 and Boot0003 look like Ubuntu installs, not sure which is your new one.  Suggest trying changing the BootOrder to use one of these first.  If the first one does not work, try the other.  I don't know why they say Unknown Device though.

Comment: Tried changing both, but still goes right to windows. When I liveboot from my USB and try installing again, it says: "The machine has already Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. What would you want to do".

Comment: You need to use `efibootmgr -o ####{,####,{####....}}`, where `####` are the `Boot####` numbers corresponding to the boot loaders you want to use, in preferred order. In your case, the results you quoted came from `Boot0002`, so you might lead with that. Alternatively, `Boot0003` looks like an Ubuntu installation, so you might try that. Your current `BootOrder` starts with `0004`, which doesn't exist, followed by `0001`, which is for Windows.

Comment: I tried changing the boot order to have all the possible Ubuntu installations before Windows Boot Manager, but it did not help. It booted straight to Windows once again.